# Can you recommend software for making such kind of animated videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, animation

I am working on making animated videos and I installed multiple programs to make animated videos, like blender, iclone7, etc.. However, I still can't find any animation software in which I can make videos like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r81Rba0vPas).

Comment: Any of the softwares you mention would do, so what exactly is the question? As it is your question is too broad to answer here, check the [tour] and the [help] to know how GD.SE works.

Comment: Blender is an extraordinary option. But the truth is that you need to work, work, and work. This animation, although pretty simple is laborious to do. You can not simplify a project that will take you a month to complete on a post. The answer to your question is **Blender**.

Answer (score 1):

Any 3d Animation application will probably do (in alphabetic order).

- [3DS max](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview)
- [Cinema 4D](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/)
- [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) (free)
- [Maya](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview)
- [Modo](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo)

...

Comment: please tell me one more thing jooja, As Im using blender currently and I learned almost all basics of blender to use it, what you say ? should I continue with blender or maya will be better for me to make such kind of videos effectively because I face some difficulties using blender and also I heard much about maya !!!

Comment: @UzairAziz Learning basics of blender takes about 6-12 months! Same with Maya